# Replacing abbreviations with complete words in dataframe reffering to a list

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) containing names with abbreviations like below:

```
Name
ABC CO
XYZ CO LTD 
S.A.L.P, S.P.A.
XXX L.P 
NUR YER SAN.TIC.LTD 
BAAB TERMINALS LTD.
```

I have to replace the abbreviations with their complete words referring to a list. So Below was my approach

```
import pandas as pd
repl = {'CO' : 'COMPANY','LTD' : 'LIMITED','L.P' : 'LIMITED PARTNERSHIP','LTD.' : 'LIMITED','.LTD' : 'LIMITED'}
repl = {rf'\b{k}\b': v for k, v in repl.items()}

df2 = df['Name'].replace(repl, regex=True)
df2
```

Below is the output;

```
0                        ABC COMPANY
1                XYZ COMPANY LIMITED
2    S.A.LIMITED PARTNERSHIP, S.P.A.
3            XXX LIMITED PARTNERSHIP
4            NUR YER SAN.TIC.LTD 
5             BAAB TERMINALS LIMITED.
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

here S.A.L.P must not replaced with L.P

Expected output :

```
    0                        ABC COMPANY
    1                XYZ COMPANY LIMITED
    2                    S.A.L.P, S.P.A.
    3            XXX LIMITED PARTNERSHIP
    4            NUR YER SAN.TIC.LIMITED
    5             BAAB TERMINALS LIMITED.
    Name: Name, dtype: object
```

The code should replace L.P with LIMITED PARTNERSHIP only when it is present separately as a different string not when it is a part of some string. Can anyone help me out with the issue please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use this regex with look-arounds that makes sure we don't have a non-whitespace before and after `key`:

```
repl = {rf'(?<!\S){re.escape(k)}(?!\S)': v for k, v in repl.items()}
```

Here:

- `(?<!\S)`: Asserts that previous character is not a non-whitespace
- `(?!\S)`: Asserts that next character is not a non-whitespace

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion. It almost solved my problem but I have a record like 'abc .LTD' corresponding lookup list have '.LTD : LIMITED' to replace the .LTD with LIMITED but it didnt  word on this record.

Comment: Can you please edit question and show expected matches?

Comment: Also try my updated code

Comment: Hi thr, tried the updated code but no luck . And also updated the input and expected output. Any help would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: You asked for `S.A.L.P must not replaced with L.P` but then want `TIC.LTD` to become `TIC.LIMITED`? Both requirements are contradictory in nature.

Answer (score 0):

Put spaces before and after the words, e.g. for L.P:

```
repl = {'CO' : 'COMPANY','LTD' : 'LIMITED',' L.P ' : ' LIMITED PARTNERSHIP '}
```